# Is it possible to check how much the audiobuffer is filled?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiobuffer

Is it possible to check how much of the audio buffer is filled ? I have a running app which can draw the audio buffers on screen, like an oscillator, but when i touch on the screen i want to stop the capturing and draw the current buffer. So i need to find out how much the buffer is filled and draw it. My current buffersize is 256.

Is it possible to achieve this with the audio buffer in iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `AudioUnitRender`, it passes you a full buffer.

With a buffer size of 256 frames, assuming you're running at 44100 frames/second (or even 11025), it doesn't seem likely that there would be a practical difference in a full buffer or not, since we're talking about such an incredibly small fraction of a second.

I'm not sure what your application is, but you may want to consider storing more data and rendering more than one buffer-length anyway, to get usable data anyway.  For example, the note A at 220Hz will only have slightly more than one period of a waveform at 44.1K within a 256-frame buffer.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oN96cucBr4
I am starting trying to just getting a sound when tapping and when the touch event occur the session should stop recording and display the "tap" frequencies on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, you'll definitely need more than a buffer's worth of data to do that.  There shouldn't be any practical reason not to go with the regular system of calling AudioUnitRender to fill your buffers for that application.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestions regarding storing the buffer(s). I am currently looking into memcpy.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably want to memcpy it into an array of your own creation that you can analyze later.  Because you're getting such a small amount of data, it may also be practical to copy the data into an NSMutableData.

Depending on the length you record, you may also want to write the data to a file.

Comment: But should i copy full audio buffers or the data within them ? What is possible +?

Comment: You just need the data in them -- for example, I in an app of mine, I call `OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(inputAudioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, kInputBus, inNumberFrames, inputBufferList);` and then copy the data out from `inputBufferList->mBuffers[i].mData` where `i` is the buffer number.

Comment: You could also look at the AurioTouch2 sample code -- it probably has answers to a lot of your questions: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks :) Are you saving in a normal NSMutablearray ? or NSData ?

Comment: Neither, because I have to save much longer data.  I cache some of the data in a primitive array and write the rest to disk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26343/discussion-between-roskvist-and-jn-pdx)